# Cannot Get Category Images To Show On Main Page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

I am working on a client's WP and I'm having a weird problem with category headers. Basically we have six categories (you can see them on the right side of the page).

When you go the main page (http://www.glossandglam.com/blog) you will see the posts without the categories next to the title EXCEPT when it's in the category BRIDAL. If you scroll down to the second post you'll see the "Bridal" image displayed next to the title. Also, when you click on the any of the categories, the category image shows next to all the posts.

I need to get the category images to show next to the titles on the main page (http://www.glossandglam.com/blog). Does anyone have any ideas?

I have tried by installed the plug-in "Category Images II" but that hasn't done the trick. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem,
i hope this below plugin will be help full to archive functionality

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-page-icons/

even you can add icons e.g green, red etc..as images in categorys, pages..

Comment: I had that installed and played with it and it added images to the sidebar but unfortunately never solved the problem I'm having with the actual posts.